# Canceled SMS on cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin

Tags: ios, windows, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have been trying to work with https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin

For Android, it works as expected. Unfortunately, I can't capture the activity for ios and windows. It opens the Messages app (as we know) but it doesn't wait for the Messages response whether it has been sent, canceled, or failed. 
It always response success. I am already using async (work on Android).

That's because I can't use the success and error parameters.

It only accepts 3 parameters:

`sms.send(number, message, options);`

It doesn't accept 5 parameters:

`sms.send(number, message, options, success, error);`

Error message is:

```
[ts] Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 5.
(method) SMS.send(phoneNumber: string | string[], message: string, options?: SmsOptions): Promise<any>
```

Has anyone able to capture Canceled SMS with this or other plugins?

P.S. I tried using other plugins but it can't even send.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error-message (and your tags) you are using the cordova-plugin with ionic-native. In this case you do not need to pass a success/error callback because the ionic-team built a nice wrapper for it so it supports promise callbacks ([docs for the `.send()` method](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms/)).

To use it you have to modify your code as follows:

```
sms.send(number, message, options).then(
  success => {
    console.log(success);
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  },
);
```

Please be aware that the callbacks only work correctly on iOS for this plugin. On the Android platform it will always return success immediately because of limitations of the operating system. For more see [this FAQ](https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin#android-immediately-passes-success-back-to-app) on their github page.